# Jade issue with accentuation encoding

Tags: javascript, html, templates, pug

I'm trying to write some words in portuguese inside my `.jade` template but the result is not as i expected:

`.jade` template

```
h1 Portfólio
```

See the problem:

```
<!-- The result that i expected -->
<h1>Portfólio</h1>

<!-- The result that comes -->
<h1>PortfÃ³lio</h1>
```

How can i fix this issue? I can't find anything about in the [docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem of Jade itself (recently renamed to [Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug)).

The Jade/Pug output (and probably the input as well) is encoded in UTF-8, but whatever program you're using to read it is interpreting it as ISO-8859-1.

Assuming you're using a web browser to read it, this problem should be fixed after declaring the character set inside the `head` of the document.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(charset='utf-8')
  body
    h1 Portfólio
```